# binary tree destructor implementation

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a class for binary tree. In this class I have a constructor which takes values from a vector and constructs a tree. This algorithm takes values from vector in preorder manner. Then I have a preorder function which prints the tree in a preorder manner. I have two functions for this -- The first one is recursive and the other is iterative.

Now comes the actual question, when I try to use these functions without the destructor of the BT class they work fine but when I include the destructor as well(basically uncomment it) then only the recursive works and iterative one does not print its output.

The case when destructor is commented is clear to me, but I do not understand what happens when i include the destructor.

**INFO ABOUT DESTRUCTOR**

This traverses the tree in preorder manner and collects the pointers to the nodes in mainStack(ms)
and then i free the top of the "ms" iteratively and then pop it from the ms.

**EDIT1**

I tried to understand this error and added print statements in the iterative
preorder function, So i first tried to include the print statement `cout << "In me "` but this did not work. Then i changed it to `cout << "In me " << endl` and this worked.(I do not even have an idea why this worked). But even this had a problem the last element which was 87 did not get printed.

Basically i got this

```
50 25 12 37 30 75 62 70 87 
In me 
50 In me 
25 In me 
12 In me 
37 In me 
30 In me 
75 In me 
62 In me 
70 In me
```

but when i included another statement `cout<< "out of me " << endl` then i got the following output

```
50 25 12 37 30 75 62 70 87 
In me 
50 In me 
25 In me 
12 In me 
37 In me 
30 In me 
75 In me 
62 In me 
70 In me 
87 out of it
```

I am a novice in C++. Any help would be appreciated.

The code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#define all(x) x.begin(), x.end()
#define vi vector<int>
#define vvi vector<vi >
#define vii vector<pair<int,int> >

using namespace std;

class node{
    public:
        int data;
        node *left;
        node *right;

        node(){
            data = 0;
            left = right = nullptr;
        }

        node(int data){
            this->data = data;
            left = right = nullptr;
        }
};

class BT{
public:
    node *root;
public:
    BT(){
    }
    BT(const vi& v){
        // create a pair with initial state 0 and having root node in it
        stack<pair<node*,int> > st;
        root = new node(v[0]);
        pair<node*,int> p(root,0);
        st.push(p);

        int idx = 1;

        while(idx < v.size())
        {
            pair<node *,int> p = st.top();
            int state = p.second;
            int val = v[idx];

            if(state == 2)
            {
                st.pop();
                continue;
            }

            if(val == -1)
            {
                // will think for here
                // p.second++;
                st.top().second++;
                idx++;
                continue;
            }

            // Now the value is not -1 and state is not 2

            node *newNode = new node(val);

            if(state == 0)
            {
                st.top().first->left = newNode;
                // p.first->left = newNode;
            }else{
                st.top().first->right = newNode;
                // p.first->right = newNode;
            }

            st.top().second++;
            st.push(pair<node*,int>(newNode,0));
            idx++;

        }
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const BT& b){
        // node *root = b.root;
        BT().printHelper(b.root,os);
        return os;
    }

    void printHelper(node *root,ostream& os){
        if(root == nullptr)
            return;

        if(root->left != nullptr)
            os << (root->left)->data;
        os <<  " <- " << root->data << " -> ";

        if(root->right != nullptr)
            os << root->right->data;
        os << endl;
        printHelper(root->left,os);
        printHelper(root->right,os);
    }

    void preOrder(){
        preOrderHelper(root);
    }

    // DO NOT TOUCH THIS...
    void preOrderHelper(node *root){
        if(root == nullptr)
            return ;

        cout << root->data << " ";
        preOrderHelper(root->left);
        preOrderHelper(root->right);
    }

    void preOrderIterative(){
        stack<node*> st;
        st.push(root);

        while(!st.empty())
        {
            // cout << "In me " << endl;
            node *removed = st.top();
            st.pop();

            cout << removed->data << " ";
            if(removed->right != nullptr)
                st.push(removed->right);
            if(removed->left != nullptr)
                st.push(removed->left);

        }
        // cout << "out of it " << endl;
    }
    ~BT(){
        stack<node*> st;

        st.push(root);
        stack<node*> ms;


        while(!st.empty()){
            node *removed = st.top(); 
            ms.push(removed);
            st.pop();

            if(removed->left != nullptr)
                st.push(removed->left);
            if(root->right != nullptr) // this is the problem @john is talking about
                st.push(removed->right);
        }

        while(!ms.empty())
        {
            delete ms.top();
            ms.top() = nullptr;
            ms.pop();
        }
        cout << "Successfully deleted..." << endl;
    }
    


};

int main(){
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
        freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
        freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
        freopen("error.txt","w",stderr);
    #endif

    vi v = {50,25,12,-1,-1,37,30,-1,-1,-1,75,62,-1,70,-1,-1,87,-1,-1};
    BT b(v);

    b.preOrder();
    cout << endl;
    b.preOrderIterative();

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT2**

Ok so i tried fixing this.What i have in my mind is that in `BT()` i should have written `root = nullptr` and in `~BT()` i should  have checked whether root is `nullptr` before proceeding further. Also i have removed `const` from  `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const BT& b)` and also changed `BT().printHelper(b.root,os)` to `b.printHelper(b.root,os)` But this still does not fix this. . .

**EDIT3**

As @john mentioned that `BT()` must be at the fault but I don't see why that should be a case as in main function i never really tried to call the `printHelper()` function. Also why should not initializing `root` in `BT()` be a problem as I never really called this constructor... I called the parametrized one.

Comment: I've tested nothing, but seems pretty clear the fault is here `BT().printHelper(b.root,os);`. Why not `b.printHelper(b.root,os);`?

Comment: `BT(){}` -- Initialize your member variables!

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/cjz46rc1b Works for me with some reordering and cleanup.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I saw your code but that it way too complicated for me. How do you really this achieve this level in c++. I wish to achieve this one day too.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow by the way what are these lines `b.preOrder([](const Node *node) {node->print(std::cout);});` and what is `fn` in `void preOrder(auto fn) const `.

Comment: @Abhishekjha `[](const Node *node) {...}` is a lambda, an anonymous function. You could write that as a named function `printHelper` and call `b.preOrder(printHelper);` although the type of that is different. Each lambda has an unique but unspecified type. The `auto fn` is another modern C++ thing, in this case a shortcut for `template <typename FN> void preOrder(FN fn) const`. What I'm doing there is passing a *callback* to `preOrder` to be invoked for every `Node`.

Answer (score 3):

This code (in `operator<<`)

```
BT().printHelper(b.root,os);
```

default constructs a temporary `BT` object and then destroys it.

The default constructor for `BT` leaves `root` uninitialised. The destructor then uses that uninitialised pointer and you have undefined behaviour.

Seems like

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const BT& b){
    // node *root = b.root;
    b.printHelper(b.root,os);
    return os;
}
```

would fix the problem but I have not tested this.

The default constructor should also be fixed since that's gaping sore in the code (or removed it you can't find a sensible implementation).

**EDIT**, ok my fix does not work because of a lack of const correctness in the class. So that's another thing that needs fixing. `printHelper` among other methods should be declared const (or made static).

Comment: I get what you are saying. But how do i fix this so basically what i have in my mind is that in default constructor i should have written `root = nullptr` and in destructor i have should have checked whether root is `nullptr` before proceeding further. Also i have removed `const` from the `operator<<`. But this still does not fix this. . .

Comment: First two points are fine. You should be adding const not removing it but if that did not fix it then you must have another bug somewhere. I'll have another look.

Comment: @Abhishekjha You have a typo in your destructor, `if(root->right != nullptr)` should be `if(removed->right != nullptr)`

Comment: my bad... I did not even notice it.

Comment: sorry for being the pain in your neck, but i have one silly question.. why did i even get this error... I mean i never really tried to call the `printHelper()` function. Also why should not initializing root in`BT()` be a problem as I never really called this constructor... I called the parametrized one.

Comment: @Abhishekjha You do call that constructor (and the destructor) here `BT().printHelper(b.root,os);` Which is why I suggested replacing with `b.printHelper(b.root,os);`

Comment: Hmm, I thought you called `operator<<` from main but I don't see it now.

Comment: @Abhishekjha *as I never really called this constructor.* -- That is not how you should approach this issue.  You are not the only entity that may call the constructor.  If you placed `BT` objects in a container, it may also call the default constructor implicitly.  Do not leave anything for granted -- make sure the entire code is correct.

Comment: @Abhishekjha Maybe all along the problem was the bug in the destructor. But I agree with Paul you have two or three potential bugs and design issues in your class and they should all be fixed.

Comment: @john yeah that is what i was also going to address that i never really used `<<` and `printHelper()` and even destructor should not have also been a problem because it was called for `b` whose root was not `nullptr` but still we got an error. Though i agree with what paul is saying.

Comment: @Abhishekjha The typo in the destructor was a real problem because of meant that null pointers got onto the stack used in that function.

Comment: @john yeah,Now that i see it the typo was the main error. Now it is all sorted. BTW is my implementation of deleting binary tree correct ^^'?